# Dynamically add select box populated data using php script in a div

Tags: php, jquery, html

I hava a page where the first select box is populated with php data and then having a "+" button so that user can repeat the same select box in the next row, but in my case when i am clicking the "+" button then nothing is loaded. If i remove the php script then its loading the select box dynamically. The problem is due to the php script in the jquery.

Below is my jquery code:

```
<script>
        function showDiv()
        {
           $('#insert').append("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-5 mb-3'><label>Item Name</label><select class='custom-select d-block w-100' id='itemname' name='itemname[]' required><option value='0'>Choose...</option><?php $result = $linkID1->query('select item_id,itemname from item_details order by itemname asc') or die("error"); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ echo '<option value='.$row[item_id].'>'.$row[itemname].'</option>'; } ?> </select><span id='inmessage'></div><div class='col-md-4 mb-3'><label>Order Size</label><select class='custom-select d-block w-100' id='unitsize' name='unitsize[]' required><option value='0'>Choose...</option></select><span id='osmessage'></div><div class='col-md-3 mb-3'><label></label><a href='#' onClick='showDiv();'><div class='plus'>+</div></a></div></div>");
        }
    </script>
```

If i remove the php part then its loading, but it will be of no use then.

Answer (score 0):

Javascripts take place client side after the page has been loaded. PHP scripts are executed on the server and generates the page send to the client. If you want the client to execute a php script, you will have to send a request to the server and receive the response on the client using a http request. T
Take a look at this explanation to get into the basics of using PHP to put content on a page without reloading the page:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa